# How to test mobile browser link directed from app in Appium?

Tags: automated-testing, appium, uiautomation, mobile-automation

In a test written in Appium, I have a scenario where clicking on android button redirects to the website. I want to check whether the site URL is valid or not. How is it possible to test the link?

Answer (score 2):

I have one solution which is useful to you.

By just seeing the Links in the UI, we may not be able to confirm if that link is working or not until we click and verify it.

To achieve this, we can use HTTPClient library to check status codes of the URLs on a page. You need to download and add it to the build path.

If request was NOT processed correctly, then the HTTP status codes may return any of the above listed codes but not a 200 status code. We can easily say whether the link is broken or not with status codes.

Now let us jump into the example, First we will try to find all anchor tags on the page by using Webdriver. By using the below syntax:

```
List<WebElement> anchorTagsList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

We need to iterate through each link and verify request response Status codes and it should be 200 if not, we will increment invalid links count

Let us look into the example :

```
package com.linked;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FindBrokenLinksExample {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private int invalidLinksCount;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void validateInvalidLinks() {

        try {
            invalidLinksCount = 0;
            List<WebElement> anchorTagsList = driver.findElements(By
                    .tagName("a"));
            System.out.println("Total no. of links are "
                    + anchorTagsList.size());
            for (WebElement anchorTagElement : anchorTagsList) {
                if (anchorTagElement != null) {
                    String url = anchorTagElement.getAttribute("href");
                    if (url != null && !url.contains("javascript")) {
                        verifyURLStatus(url);
                    } else {
                        invalidLinksCount++;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Total no. of invalid links are "
                    + invalidLinksCount);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null)
            driver.quit();
    }

    public void verifyURLStatus(String URL) {

        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            // verifying response code and The HttpStatus should be 200 if not,
            // increment invalid link count
            ////We can also check for 404 status code like response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 404
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200)
                invalidLinksCount++;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the example of clicking a button in an app then opening a browser?